# this in inner function of object method

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I know that there are ES6 arrow functions that solves this, but that is not the question. I don't know why this is not working? I think I heard somewhere that it is a mistake in language design. I want to know underlying mechanism why this is not working or some useful links about this.

```
var test = {
  firstname: 'David',
  fn: function() {

     return ['one', 'two', 'tree'].map(function() { 
        this.firstname;  // why is this undefined?

    })
  }
}
console.log(test.fn());
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside you *Array.prototype.map* function *this* references to the window object. To fix this you can bind it like below:

```
var test = {
  firstname: 'David',
  fn: function() {

     return ['one', 'two', 'tree'].map(function() { 
        console.log(this.firstname);  // and now it will be your expected result

    }.bind(this))
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mx8swvk/), also [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is the link about *Function.prototype.bind* method

I hope it will help you

Comment: yes,tnx! Why Douglas Crockford says that it was a mistake in language design?

Comment: [Here](https://nemisj.com/js-without-new-and-this/), part **Scope substitution & why no “this” usage** a good explanation around _this_ keyword